# Maximum call stack size exceeded on trigger click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I really want to do something simple. On click on a certain element, I trigger a click on another element but I get the below error on my console.

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

My code is as below;

```
$('body').on('click', '.actual-click-element', function(event) { 
    $('.trigger-click-element').trigger('click');
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

I wonder why am am getting this error and I don't see how this is recursive. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, when you click on the body, you issue a click event which presumably bubbles up to the body and issues a click event which presumably bubbles up to the body and issues a click event...

Comment: Also, you are missing a closing quote.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Surely because `.trigger-click-element` is descendant of `.actual-click-element`...

To avoid recursive call, you could use jq [triggerHandler()](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/):

> Events triggered with .triggerHandler() do not bubble up the DOM
>   hierarchy; if they are not handled by the target element directly,
>   they do nothing.

```
$('body').on('click', '.actual-click-element', function(event) { 
    $('.trigger-click-element').triggerHandler('click');
    event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Now if `$('.trigger-click-element')` returns more than one element, you could use:

```
$('.trigger-click-element').each(function(){$(this).triggerHandler('click');});
```

Comment: cheers @A.Wolff i totally overlooked that.