# delegate panel heading click to inner link for bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, bootstrap-accordion

I have a bootstap panel accordion:

```
<div class="modal-body">
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
               <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="collapsed">
               Annual </a>
            </h4>
         </div>
         <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
               <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
               Semi-Annual </a>
            </h4>
         </div>
         <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Instead of clicking the tiny `<a>` link, I want the entire `.panel-heading` to trigger the click of the inner `<a>`.

I can't use the following code because of the obvious `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error:

```
panelHeadings.on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).find('a').click(); // trigger('click') behaves the same
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

...but using the code from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39620646/maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-trigger-click) causes nothing to happen when I click:

```
panelHeadings.on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).find('a').triggerHandler('click');
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Is there another way to trigger the click event on the inner a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach to do that - using [BS-collapse-toggle](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-toggle):

Default event prevented for the anchor tag and a new event is added to the `panel-heading`:

```
$('div#accordion .panel-heading a[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});

$('div#accordion .panel-heading').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.collapse').collapse('toggle');
});
```

```js
$('div#accordion .panel-heading a[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
});

$('div#accordion .panel-heading').on('click', function() {
 $(this).parent().find('.collapse').collapse('toggle');
});
```

```css
div#accordion .panel-heading {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
               <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="collapsed">
               Annual </a>
            </h4>
         </div>
         <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
               <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
               Semi-Annual </a>
            </h4>
         </div>
         <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the collapse() function!

Comment: Sure. I just did the same thing in an application I'm working on. :) Anyway, glad to help.